# Simplest Midi Editor Player with animated keyboard?

Tags: music

I need a simplest program to load, edit (cut, add, modify notes, add, delete, merge tracks ...) I need to do some basic works on midifiles to suit my needs then save them.
I also need to play back while editing midifiles and see notes appearing in the virtual keyboard.
Do you know any program that could do it but in simplest way ?

Something like synthesia but with complete editing midifiles features

Thanks

Comment: Asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly (which you partly did). Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. The more precise you point out your requirements, the better are your chances for good fitting answers, so feel encouraged to [edit] your question ;) Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

[Anvil Studio](http://anvilstudio.com/) is a free software that comes with a MIDI editor. You can look into that.

Among its features are:

> - Record notes from an external MIDI keyboard.
> - Enter notes from Computer keyboard while real-time recording or manually composing.
> - Select, Copy, Edit, Paste notes.
> - The Perform screen lets you wire together on-screen modules for real-time manipulation of MIDI sounds.
> - Option to echo to SoundCard while recording MIDI, even when recording from external keyboard.